# Using Laplace Transform to solve $y''-2y'+2y=0$ with initial conditions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, integral-transforms

I am in a class called "Mathematics for Engineers" and I recently had this question on a quiz. I would like to know if anything is wrong with my solution; the comments from my professor don't make any sense to me:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should ask your instructor about it... However, it could be because you use the same variable to denote the original $y(t)$ and the laplace transform function $Y(s).$  The very top comment must have been interpretted by the instructor $\mathcal{L}(y(t))=y(s).$

Comment: @VivekKaushik Yes I am going to talk to the instructor tomorrow, I just wanted to check if there are any obvious mistakes. I think you're right about legibility; I think she thought I wrote "Suppose $y(t)$ is a solution and $L(y(t))=y(s)$.

Comment: Though I think the difference between my capital and lower case $y's$is pretty clear

Comment: Your solution $y(t)$ is correct, which I confirmed.

Comment: I think your instructor is having a problem differentiating between the lowercase y and uppercase Y. You are right in that it is customary to capitalize a variable's Laplace transform, but you may be able to make it more obvious by writing horizontal lines above and below the capital Y. I can't find an image for Y but [here is what it would look like for X](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-91rFLxuBZpY/VI5fmJqLEuI/AAAAAAAAN_I/46gN-O0IJXo/s1600/11.jpg). Of course you can also state that L{y(t)} = Y(s) in addition to this to make it clearer.

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 At the very top of the image I stated that L{y(t)} = Y(s)

Comment: I meant that what you put there was not incorrect, just that it was read incorrectly. So you could still leave that in, _in addition_ to using the top/bottom lines (or some other method) to differentiate between lowercase y and uppercase Y.

Comment: yeah make sure you show him the difference

Comment: Obviously, your professor couldn't distinguish between your $y$ and $Y$. Neither could I.